# Blenderkit addon - Error while trying to enable the addon in Blender 2.9

Tags: add-on, error

[image][image: Error-while enabling Blenderkit addon]

I am getting this error when I try to enable Blenderkit addon in blender 2.9, I am not sure why, it was working fine before updating to blender 2.9, please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who might have the same problem, I found a solution thanks to the addon developers, I guess there was a conflict between several downloaded versions of blender, so to fix the issue, I went to the following path

C:\Users[Your Username]\AppData\Roaming\Blender foundation

I deleted the blender foundation folder and restarted blender and now I was able to enable the addon again

make sure to show hidden files in order to see App Data folder.